# They don't want HER to think THEM not to appreciate

Tags: sentence-construction, objects

I've got such task. My friend said that the first variant is better. But I supposed the second one to be more clear. In my country the english constructions like these are called as *"complex objects"*. Please tell me what you'd use and why?

> 1.They wouldn't want *her to think* **them not to appreciate** what she has done for them.
>
> Here are two *"complex object"*: *"her to think"* and *"them not to appreciate"* going one after another.
>
> 2.They wouldn't want *her to think* **that they don't appreciate** what she has done for them.
>
> Here is one *"complex object"*: *"her to think"*.

Also:

> 3.Maybe for fun, can I add many complex objects one after another? It's not convinient for perception of course but I wonder whether it is grammatical or not.
>
> *I don't want her to consider me to want her to make me do my work better for our kids to have a lot of toys.*
>
> 4.And can the complex object be in the perfect or continuous forms?
>
> *I don't want her to have done that work. I want her to be hearing me (or her hearing me).*

---

Note that the second sentence was originally the following when one of the answers was given:

2.They wouldn't want her to think **that they don't appreciate that** she has done for them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91167/discussion-on-question-by-user79871-they-dont-want-her-to-think-them-not-to-app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with your friend the first sentence is difficult to read, and I actually had to read it a couple of times to understand it.

Whereas your's is the version I would say.

Why anybody would prefer a sentence with 2 complex sections when 1 will do is beyond me.

Comment: thank you. We can prefer #1 because there is a english rule which our teachers score as the main rule: the shorter the better. So "them not to appreciate" is shorter than "that they don't appreciate". And that's why we should use the shorter variant. You, as a native, saing that such complex objects usually are not used many times one after another. But is it grammatical? If it is, I can use it as a language joke in a converisation or a letter (example #3).

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence could be modified a bit as

> They wouldn't want her to think that they don't appreciate **what** she has done for them.

Comment: Thank you! So several the complexes are not possible? it's not grammatical?

Comment: Well, the sentence that you have in the point 3 in your question doesn't make sense. Honestly, to me it sounds like a jumbled up sentence.

Comment: Ok, here is other one: they wouldnt want her to think them to make her work harder. :)

Comment: The usage of the word 'them' in these sentences actually make no sense. You could say it as (if my assumption of what you're trying to say is correct): They wouldn't want her to think, that they're making her work harder.

Comment: Ok, what about this: I don't want her to consider me to want her to make me do my work better. Is it grammatical? I understand, nobody says such way.

Comment: @user79871 That last sentence is gibberish, sorry.

Comment: @Lambie thanks for new word gibberish in my glossary! I like it. I know that it's not used but is that sentence grammatical?

Comment: @user79871 "I don't want her to consider me to want her to make me do my work better." =not grammatical.

Comment: @Lambie ok, how many constructions like that do I can use one after another? As I can understand you, not more than one. But what about such sentence: they wouldnt want her to think them to make her work harder. :)

Comment: @user79871 "how many constructions like that do I can use one after another?" More gibberish. I cannot understand that at all.

Comment: @user79871 try to keep it simple. Why do you want to complicate your sentences and make them sound meaningless

Comment: @Lambie you and Kashyap are very unfriendly. Id like to know all possibilities. Whats wrong with it? Lambie, whats wrong with my question? Please do rephrase it!

Comment: @user79871 I want to be anything but unfriendly. I'm trying to help you but I don't exactly understand what is that you're specifically trying to understand. My main point is that the sentences that you're writing can be written in a very simple manner.

Comment: @KashyapMaheshwari if you look at my question you'll see that I and my friend-teacher discussed the complex objects. As you can see my opinion was the variant you has choosen too. But then I would wonder if there are the rules? My teacher has choosen the variant you dont like. Sorry, but, if you really know, can you just say what's wrong and why?

Comment: @KashyapMaheshwari as you can see, for example, Jason Bassford said that #3 is grammatical but is not easy because of loosing track of what it means by the end. It's very important for me.

Comment: @Lambie , but Ive found only one err in: "how many constructions like that *do I can* use one after another?". It should be *can I". Yes? Sorry for the mistake.